# Depth first maze generating algorithm c++ implementation

Tags: c++

I implemented a simple maze generator as practice and I wonder what can I do to improve my C++ skills. I saw this implementation and used it as an inspiration for some parts of my code [link](https://github.com/corporateshark/random-maze-generator/blob/master/Maze.cpp).

I am a little bit confused about usage of the 'inline' keyword. Should the definition of an `inline` declared method be in .cpp file? I read somewhere that inline method sources should be visible to users of those methods. For small scale programs like this should I keep everything in one file or separate each struct/class to .h & .cpp?

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

enum Direction{ Left, Right, Up, Down };

Direction operator!(const Direction& dir){
    return Direction( (dir==Left || dir==Up) ? dir+1 : dir-1 );
}

struct Coords{
    int x, y;
    static const Coords directionOffset[];
};
const Coords Coords::directionOffset[] = {
    Coords{-1, 0 }, // left
    Coords{ 1, 0 }, // right
    Coords{ 0,-1 }, // up
    Coords{ 0, 1 }  // down
};
Coords operator+(const Coords& left, const Coords& right){
    return Coords{left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y };
}

struct MazeCell{
    unsigned char connections = 0;

    inline bool isConnected(Direction dir) const;
    inline void connect(Direction dir);
    inline bool visited() const;
    static const unsigned char connectionMask[];
};

bool MazeCell::isConnected(Direction dir) const{
    return connections & connectionMask[dir];
}
void MazeCell::connect(Direction dir){
    connections |= connectionMask[dir];
}
bool MazeCell::visited() const{
    return connections;
}
const unsigned char MazeCell::connectionMask[] = {
    (1 << 0), // left
    (1 << 1), // right
    (1 << 2), // up
    (2 << 3)  // down
};

struct MazePosition;
class Maze{
    friend MazePosition;
    unsigned int width,height;
    MazeCell* cells;

public:
    Maze(unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
    MazePosition at(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const;

private:
    bool succsesfullyConnectedToNeighbour(Coords& cellCoords);
    inline void connect(Coords& from, Coords& to, Direction dir);
    inline bool areCoordsValid(const Coords& coords) const;
    inline MazeCell& cellAt(const Coords& coords) const;
};
void Maze::connect(Coords& from, Coords& to, Direction dir){
    cellAt(from).connect(dir);
    cellAt(to).connect(!dir);
}
bool Maze::areCoordsValid(const Coords& coords) const {
    return coords.x >= 0          && coords.y >= 0 &&
           coords.x <  (int)width && coords.y <  (int)height;
}
MazeCell& Maze::cellAt(const Coords& coords) const {
    if(!areCoordsValid(coords)){std::cout << "hit bad";}
    return cells[coords.x + coords.y*width];
}
Maze::Maze(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) : width(width), height(height) {
    cells = new MazeCell[width*height];
    Coords currentCellCoords{0,0};
    std::stack<Coords> visitedCellsStack;
    visitedCellsStack.push(currentCellCoords);

    while(true){
        if(succsesfullyConnectedToNeighbour(currentCellCoords)){
            visitedCellsStack.push(currentCellCoords);
        }else{
            currentCellCoords = visitedCellsStack.top();
            visitedCellsStack.pop();
            if(visitedCellsStack.empty()) break;
        }
    }
}
bool Maze::succsesfullyConnectedToNeighbour(Coords& cellCoords){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> random(1,4);
    Direction random_direction = Direction(random(eng));

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        auto next_rand_direction = Direction( (random_direction + i)%4 );
        auto neighbour_coords = Coords::directionOffset[next_rand_direction] + cellCoords;

        if( areCoordsValid(neighbour_coords) && !cellAt(neighbour_coords).visited() ){
            connect(cellCoords, neighbour_coords, next_rand_direction);
            cellCoords = neighbour_coords;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

struct MazePosition{
    const Maze& maze;
    Coords currentCoords;
    MazePosition(const Maze& maze, Coords coords) : maze(maze), currentCoords(coords){}
    
    bool canGo(Direction dir){
        return maze.cellAt(currentCoords).isConnected(dir);
    }

    void go(Direction dir){
        if(canGo(dir))
            currentCoords = currentCoords + Coords::directionOffset[dir];
    }
};

MazePosition Maze::at( unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const{
    return MazePosition(*this,Coords{(int)x, (int)y}); 
}

int main(){
    const static int w = 30;
    const static int h = 70;
    Maze maze(w,h);

    //printing maze 
    std::cout << std::string(2*w, '_') << '\n';
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < h; y++){
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < w; x++){
            if(maze.at(x,y).canGo(Left)) std::cout << ' ';
            else::std::cout << '|';

            if(maze.at(x,y).canGo(Down)) std::cout << ' ';
            else::std::cout << '_';

            if( x==(w-1) && !maze.at(x,y).canGo(Right) ) std::cout << '|';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: The `inline` keyword is at best a hint to the compiler it isn't necessary because modern compilers will decide if the function can be inlined or not. At one time it generated optimized code  but that is no longer true. See this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method.

Comment: Welcome to code review, how much of the code in the question is borrowed from the link. If it is more than 50%, this question may be off-topic and put on hold or closed.

Comment: Thanks! I borrowed just a concept for storing connections between cells as individual bits and implemented it in a more OOP way, but generally my code is a lot different than the one from the link which is not in OOP style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points that might be useful:

- Firstly, don't worry about having small header/source files. It's generally good practice to put structs/classes in separate files.
- You declare `MazeCell` and `MazePosition` as `struct`. I would still use `class` here. It's a matter of preference but a pretty good rule is to use `struct` when you just want a container for data with no methods or added functionality.
- Don't really worry about inline because any decent compiler will do this for you.
- `unsigned` can be used instead of `unsigned int` and is more idiomatic.
- Your use of `unsigned int` in `Maze` is inconsistent with your use of `int` in `Coords`. This is causing a lot of C style `(int)` casts. If you just continue to use `int` instead, you can forget all of these and prevent the chance of overflow.
- You never `delete[] cells;` in `Maze`! As is, the class should also have a destructor, copy constructor and copy assignment operator. An easier way to solve this though would be to use `std::vector<MazeCell>` for your cells.
- `Maze::succsesfullyConnectedToNeighbour(...)` is confusingly named. Ignoring the typo, it does not indicate that it will change the coords you pass it. Maybe `bool Maze::connectToNeighbour(const Coords& currentCell, Coords& neighbourCell)` would be more appropriate?
- In `Maze::succsesfullyConnectedToNeighbour(...)` you should declare your random device, engine & distribution as static. You are not intended to construct new ones every time you need a random number